# Access data from my table of sqlserver in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i am designing a project in .net 4.0 using mvc3. my table name "logindata" is stored in sql server 2008. i want to access rows of that table in my project model class. So please suggest me what connction string i should use and where i should specify table name to access data from that table.?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest looking online for some tutorials. Scott Hanselman has some great videos of this kind of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I highly suggest reading the LINQ to SQL tutorial by Scott Guthrie**

LINQ to SQL is a very efficient and simple method for retrieving database data and placing it into easily-accessible pre-configured, adjustable business objects.

I think you will find it a good first step.

- [Part 1: Introduction to LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2: Defining our Data Model Classes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx)
- [Part 3: Querying our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 4: Updating our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 5: Binding UI using the <asp:LinqDataSource> Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx)
- [Part 6: Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 7: Updating our Database using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 8: Executing Custom SQL Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx)
- [Part 9: Using a Custom LINQ Expression with the <asp:LinqDataSource> Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx)